# View in Oracle — syntax error

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT D1.DISTRICT_NAME, E1.EMP_FNAME, E1.EMP_LNAME, T1.TAX_YEAR, T1.DATE_LAST_CALC
FROM DISTRICT AS D1, EMPLOYEE AS E1, TOTAL_PAB AS T1
WHERE T1.DATE_LAST_CALC BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-04'
OR '2015-06-01' - T1.DATE_LAST_CALC > 175
ORDER BY DISTRICT_NAME, EMP_LNAME;
```

I'm trying to create a view in Oracle.

Write a query (and save as a view) to display all employees that need to have their TOTAL_PAB recalculated.
They need to be recalculated if their DATE_LAST_CALC is between April 1st, 2015 and April 4th, 2015
(there was a virus report in that time frame so they want to recalculate these) OR the difference between June 1st, 2015 (beginning of fiscal year) and the DATE_LAST_CALC is greater than 175 days. Sort by the
District’s name and then by the employee’s last name

When I try to run this, I get `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.  I don't know what is wrong with the syntax. Any help please.

Comment: Are you sure that subtracting a date from another date in oracle yields a number of days?  And why would it yield days and not, say, seconds?  Or fortnights for that matter?

Comment: @MikeNakis: yes, this is how it is defined (and clearly documented) in Oracle

Comment: Yes it says that date is stored in units of days.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 5):

Oracle does not support the `AS` keyword for table alias, so

```
from district as d1, employee as e1, total_pab as t1
```

needs to be:

```
from district d1, employee e1, total_pab t1
```

---

But that query has more problems.

Because you are using the outdated, ancient *implicit* joins in the `where` clause you don't notice that you are missing the join conditions for the three tables.

If you rewrite this to use a proper `JOIN` operator this immediately gets visible:

```
SELECT d1.district_name, e1.emp_fname, e1.emp_lname, t1.tax_year, t1.date_last_calc
FROM district d1
  JOIN employee e1 ON ?????
  JOIN total_pab t1 ON ?????
```

Also the condition: `or '2015-06-01' - t1.date_last_calc > 175` is a bug happen to wait. `'2015-06-01'` is not a `date` value, it's a string constant which is *implicitly* converted to date. It's better to use an explicit `date` value. Either using standard SQL literal:

```
date '2015-06-01' - t1.date_last_calc > 175`
```

or using Oracle's `to_date()` function:

```
to_date('2015-06-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd') - t1.date_last_calc > 175` is a bug
```

The same is true for your `between` condition.

---

<sup>There is also no reason to write **everything** in uppercase in SQL</sup>

Comment: @apc: there is no `distinct` in the query